# Nested Hypervisor - Hyper-V 2016 inside ESXi 6.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v

I have a VMware ESXi 6.5 running on Dell Precision Rack 7910
Intel Xeon CPU E5-2643 v3 @ 3.40GHZ

I'm planning to nest install Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016 Standalone (free version). 
How do I go about checking compatibility for this nested hypervisor setup?

Comment: Science experiment.

Comment: It should work if you follow VMware's instructions for enabling nested virtualization for the VM. 2019 works better though. Though I agree with ewwhite, you should have just tried it.

Comment: If you flip it other side, ESXi 6.7 inside Hyper-V 2019, it works quite well :)

Comment: As this looks like a potential XY problem - what underlying problem are you solving by nesting hypervisors?  It may be that there are other solutions to consider.

Comment: @RobPearson I'm needing to recreate a customer issue but do not have luxury of ordering new HW due to time constraints.

Comment: Here is a consolidated page on all the articles written about the Nested Virtualization (nested ESXi, Hyper-V, etc) and all the goodies that are "Not Supported". https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/nested-virtualization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for getting the nested Hyper-V guests to connect to the external network, you probably need to enable Promiscuous Mode on the ESXi vSwitch, and additionally you may need to enable MAC Address Spoofing on the network adapter of the  Hyper-V guest. Images below:

1. ESXi vSwitch:

[image]

2. Hyper-V guest network adapter:

[image]

Comment: Setting ESXi vSwitch to Promiscuous Mode: Accept resolved my issue. It was not necessary to Enable MAC address spoofing in my setup. VM can still be reached outside of Hyper-V by being attached to External Virtual Switch. Thanks for the helpful screenshots, you rock!